# Følner sequences with weird shapes

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, amenability

Let $G$ be a discrete and finitely generated group. Recall that $\{F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a *Følner sequence* if $|g F_n \cup F_n|/|F_n| \rightarrow 1$ for every $g \in G$. As is well known, existence of a Følner sequence is equivalent to amenability of $G$.

It is often said that Følner sequences have *strange* shapes. My soft question is: which examples do we have that support this claim? Of course, if $G$ is of subexponential growth then a subsequence of balls forms a Følner sequence, and this does not have a *weird* shape. Hence, more specifically: which examples of groups of exponential growth do we know that have explicit Følner sequences not made of balls?

As instances of the examples I am asking for, [Star-shaped Folner sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143135/star-shaped-folner-sequence) asks for Følner sets of a certain form, while an answer of [Folner sets and balls](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148995/folner-sets-and-balls) gives explicit sequences made of *rectangles* (as opposed to balls). Likewise, the ***ax + b*** group has a Følner sequence made of rectangles where one side is exponentially larger than the other.

Comment: Maybe Fölner sequences of group extensions fit the bill, see e.g. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/some-notes-on-amenability/

Comment: It's quite subjective... you could have a "weird" subsequence of "weird"-shaped balls. Also on $\mathbf{Z}$ the union of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with any "weird" subset of cardinal $o(n)$ is Følner. Also in polycyclic groups or the $ax+b$ group the rectangles you mention look all but weird for me. The exponential size is with respect to matrix coordinates, but it's of linear size in the word length.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the premise of the question though, I have more often (= at least once) heard "there is a unique choice for the Fölner sequence", which does not imply they are not strange, but does imply they are natural (I guess this statement refers to mutual tileability).

Comment: I do disagree with the statement that balls are natural shapes. For example on the lamplighter group, balls look pretty strange, while Fölner sequences are beautiful.

Comment: @YCor you are indeed right that "weird" is subjective. I just meant Folner sequences that are not balls. Hence your example of $\mathbb{Z}$ fits the question, but I'd like some other examples.

Comment: @VilleSalo I've heard more than once that Følner sets are usually strange, but this is of course personal. I do agree with you on the lamplighter, and it fits the question perfectly.

Comment: Fair enough. I have not talked to everyone!

Comment: In a sense I don't think this is the right question. In amenable groups of exponential growth balls are seldom/never Følner (even after extraction). Also perturbing Følner $(F_n)$ by subsets of size $o(F_n)$ yields Følner, so one should phrase the question in a way to ignore this. On the other hand, in polycyclic groups or lamplighter groups, one can always find Følner subsets $(F_n)$ that are trapped between the $cn$-ball and the $Cn$-ball (see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603138). This behavior is the most "regular" one, and doesn't qualify as "weird".

Comment: @YCor even if the question is not well-posed (which it isn't, as you rightly claim), I think it still makes sense, and your and Ville Salo are answering it quite well. I was looking for a list of groups where balls are not Folner sets, but these are known (and explicit). I could delete the question if needs be, but I think this might be useful for somebody later.

Comment: @DiegoMartínez two comments: (1) the "rectangles" you mention are actually "star-shaped" in the sense of my question,... so those two do not really go in opposition. (2) it can be useful to reduce the arbitrarity in the Folner set by restricting to "optimal" Folner sets. Definition: let $I(n) = inf |\partial A|/|A|$ (where the inf runs over all sets $A$ of size $\leq n$) be the isoperimetric profile. Then a set $F$ is optimal if $I(|F|) = |\partial F|/|F|$. If you look at such sets then they probably are not "strange" at all (since they must be extremely wellchosen).But they sure are no balls.

Comment: The problem with optimal sets is that there is essentially no group where it's proven what they are. For example, it's an long-standing open question to prove what are such sets in the (continuous) Heisenberg group (although the conjectured shape is well-described). That was my motivation for [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218460/sharp-isoperimetry-in-the-discrete-heisenberg-group) question. Optimal sets have the fun property that they have a relatively good Cheeger constant (but it can be much lower than their isoperimetric ratio see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11733) ).

Comment: @ARG your points are appreciated. You are indeed right that the rectangles I mention in the post are star-shaped (as they should), but morally speaking not every star-shaped set needs be a rectangle (whatever that means). I didn't mention optimal Folner sets as I'm not really interested in whether they are optimal, only whether they are balls, but the optimality does indeed get rid of some technicalities the question does not get into.

Comment: @DiegoMartínez Correct. I thought, that there might still be important informations in the linked question. For example: we don't know of any group of exponential growth where Folner sequences are balls. However, if $G$ and $H$ are amenable, then one can show that $G \rtimes H$ is amenable and that Folner sets are of the Form $E \times F$. So you should rather expect "rectangular" Folner sets (whenever that makes sense) than ball-like Folner sets. This becomes more obvious when you look at the optimal Folner sets. Because, even in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ optimal Folner sets are "rectangular".

Comment: @ARG your post and this discussion does raise the question of whether Følner sets may be assumed to be rectangular. I personally don't know any example when this does not happen (as it does in extensions). Even in some more intricate cases, as topological full groups of minimal $\mathbb{Z}$-actions on the Cantor space, Følner sets turn out to be *rectangular*.

Comment: @DiegoMartínez I kind of agree but "rectangular" only make sense if your group splits:following the proof that a semi-direct prodcut of amenable groups is amenable, you get "rectangular"sets.But I'm not sure if this is true for non-split extensions(can't remember good examples).And this surely can't be true for simple amenable groups (because "rectangular" does make sense there). Lastly, it's just one of many sequences,e.g. in nilpotent groups you have "rectangular"and "round"Folner sequences.It looks like[to me]that the "rectangular"option is the one that comes out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

The algebra is more useful here than pictures, but the pictures are fun, so here goes. To substantiate my comment about lamplighter, quick renderings of a typical ball and Følner set of lamplighter. Actually I don't know which of these is prettier, but the Følner set is actually the one that looks more like a ball.

The two pictures are taken from different angles and thus form a stereogram, so if you look at the leftmost picture with your right eye and vice versa your stereopsis should kick in. I find this helpful, if you don't you can ignore one of the pictures.

First, the ball or radius $3$ with the generators where the head moves. When the head moves to the right, you go up the diagram. I'm using some conventions, which are hopefully guessable.

[image: Lamplighter ball]

Here's a typical Følner set with the same generators.

[image: Lamplighter Følner]

Comment: These are great, thanks! These are precisely what I was asking for. However, what do you mean from "different angles"? Each pair is identical, right? Mind you, I think it's more or less clear without the need from another angle, but I spent several minutes looking for the 7 differences.

Comment: @DiegoMartínez: note that if you spent several minutes looking for the 7 differences, then you are using a suboptimal algorithm for that game. A much better algorithm is what is suggested in the post, looking at one picture with one eye, and at the other with the other eye.

Comment: I was looking at these again yesterday and you are right. Again, thanks for these.

Answer (score 2):

This question was popular in the 50s and 60s after Folner theorem was proved. Many examples of weird Folner sets were constructed. The typical examples of groups where Folner sets are nor balls are lamplighter groups and the wreath products of infinite cyclic gtoups. For a more recent papers see Anna Erschler. On isoperimetric profiles of finitely generated groups. Geom. Dedicata, 100:157–171, 2003 and the references therein.

Comment: What's the precise meaning of "groups where Følner sets are not balls"?

Comment: @YCor I guess dodd means amenable groups where no subsequence of balls forms a Folner sequence. I don't know whether that helps.

Comment: With such a definition, this might precisely be the class of amenable groups with exponential growth (and still I disagree that these are weird! rather I'd say that balls are complicated subsets).

Comment: @YCor you're right, but let me rephrase into "amenable groups where Følner sets are known explicitly, but balls are not known to be Følner". These are necessarily of exponential growth, but may be a strictly smaller class of groups. Regarding the use of "weird" I guess it's mostly personal taste, but I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to your non-soft question is that the following groups all have [at least one] generating set where balls are **known** not to be Folner, but some other ("rectangular") sequence is: solvable Baumslag-Solitar, some wreath products (including the lamplighter), some extensions of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ (those given by a matrix with no eigenvalues of norm 1), some $ax+b$ groups and basically nearly any amenable groups of exponential growth whose growth series is rational and has been computed (see below for details).

*"strangeness" of Folner sets:*
As mentioned in the question, [a subsequence of the sequence of] balls form a natural Folner sequence in any group of subexponential growth. Now, as pointed out by others, balls (w.r.t. to some finite generating set) are fairly "ugly". This can be made precise if one considers the concept of an optimal Folner set:

Let $I(n)= \displaystyle \inf_{|A| \leq n} \dfrac{|\partial A|}{|A|}$ (the $\inf$ runs over all sets $A$ of size $\leq n$) be the isoperimetric profile.
Then a set $F$ is optimal if $I(|F|)=\dfrac{|\partial F|}{|F|}$.
In words: if a set $E$ is not larger [cardinality-wise] than $F$, then it's isoperimetric ratio $\dfrac{|\partial E|}{|E|}$, does not beat the isoperimetric ratio of $F$.

One can check (using the Loomis-Whitney inequality) that optimal Folner sets in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ (w.r.t. the usual generating set) are [hyper]cubes (or that they tend to have a rectangular form).
This is an unambiguous way of saying that balls are "clumsy" Folner sets. By comparison optimal sets are not "weird" at all (since they must be extremely well-chosen).

For more on strangeness, see the side notes below.

---

*Explicit examples:*
Next, given a group of exponential growth, it's an open question whether any subsequence of the sequence of balls is Folner. I gave a [partial answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148995/folner-sets-and-balls/235348#235348) which shows this is not case when the group [together with the choice of generating set] has pinched exponential growth. This includes many wreath products, solvable Baumslag-Solitar groups and some extensions of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ (see link for details).

These groups can all be written as semi-direct products.
If $G$ and $H$ are amenable, then one can show that $G \rtimes H$ is amenable and that Folner sets are of the Form $E_n \times F_n$ (where $E_n$ [resp. $F_n$] is a Folner sequence of $G$ [resp. $H$]).
In that sense, the Folner sets that we come across (lazily, in the sense that they are produced by a general proof) in such groups are "rectangular".

Hence the groups mentioned above [solvable Baumslag-Solitar, some metabelian groups, groups whose growth series is rational and do not have a two poles at the radius of convergence (which includes many wreath products and $ax+b$-groups)] are a direct answer to your second question (for some generating set). One knows that balls (w.r.t. generating sets) are not Folner but some "rectangular" set is (just to be precise: there could be groups with a single pole which are not semi-direct products or extensions of amenable groups; for these groups [if any are known] there are no "rectangular" sets).

For non-split extensions a description of the Folner sets was [given over there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928075/extensions-of-amenable-groups) by Ycor.
Note one could adapt the meaning of "rectangular" for non-split extensions: by taking a preimage of the Folner set of the quotient times some Folner set of the subgroup.

So now one might think that "rectangular" (and no longer balls) sets are favourites. But then there are also simple groups of intermediate growth [see this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122199/is-it-true-that-every-f-g-infinite-simple-group-has-exponential-growth). And (if not for such groups, then for other simple groups of subexponential growth) I guess that balls are the only candidates one has.

Basically, I think the problem has more to do with how we construct amenable groups. We always use the four properties of amenability (extension, subgroup, quotient and direct limit). So ones start with growth as basic criterium, and uses those four properties (there are possibly many ways to do it). This will give you the known Folner sets for a given group. As a silly example you could say that natural Folner sets in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ are cylinders (balls in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ times balls in $\mathbb{Z}$).

---

**Side Note 1:** it's an long-standing open question to prove what are such sets in the (continuous) Heisenberg group (although the conjectured shape is well-described). That was my motivation for [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218460/sharp-isoperimetry-in-the-discrete-heisenberg-group) question.

**Side Note 2:** As pointed out by Ycor, given a Folner sequence $F_n$ you can make it "as weird as you want" by considering an arbitrary sequence of finite sets $E_n$ with $\dfrac{|E_n|}{|F_n|} \to 0$. One the advantage of considering optimal Folner sequences would be to avoid such set-ups (the obvious disadvantage, is that there are almost no groups where optimal sets are known). A further note is that adding such a set $E_n$ has no influence on the invariant measure one obtains (for a fixed ultrafilter). Note that translating the sets can have an effect on the limit measure.

**Side Note 3:** Here is another aspect of the "strangeness" of Folner sets. Consider the sequence $P_n = [2^n,2^{n+1}]$, $M_n = [-2^{n+1},-2^n]$, as well as $A_n = (-1)^n \cdot P_n$ of sets in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then consider the function $f(n) = \mathrm{sign}(n)$. The invariant mean one gets from $P_n$ on $f$ is 1 (whatever the ultrafilter you choose), the one you get with $M_n$ is $-1$ (again, whatever the ultrafilter) and finally the one you get with $A_n$ depends on the ultafilter you choose. And you could construct for any real number in $[-1,1]$ a sequence $R_n$ which converges to that number (indenpendently of the ultrafilter). It's not too hard to construct a sequence which can, depending on the ultrafilter, converge to any rational number in $[-1,1]$.